# Bar chart showing proportion of factor variable taking a certain value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set which is similar to

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(
  c(rep.int(x = 0, times =7), 1:3), 
  c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  c(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, NA)))
names(df) <- c("cars", "sex", "status")
df$sex <- factor(df$sex, labels = c("male", "female"))
df$status <- factor(df$status, labels = c("bad", "ok", "good"))
df$car <- (df$cars > 0) # Person has at least 1 car
```

I would like to use ggplot2 to make a faceted bar chart with the following characteristics:

- Facet by the categorical variables (sex and status in this example)
- Each panel contains one bar per level of that factor (e.g. male and female for "sex")
- Each bar shows how many percent of the total observations for that level of that factor, that has at least 1 car (e.g. percent of males with at least 1 car)

How can I do this smoothly in ggplot2? (Or alternatively, do you have a better suggestion of how to represent these proportions graphically?)

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet, or do you just want us to do this for you?

Comment: Yes, I have. However, the results were so far from what I wanted that I chose not to include them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

df.long = melt(df, measure.vars=c('sex', 'status'))
df.long.summary = ddply(df.long, .(variable, value), summarize, cars=sum(cars > 0) / length(cars))

ggplot(data=df.long.summary, aes(x=value, y=cars)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales='free_x') +
  scale_y_continuous(formatter='percent')
```

[image]

(BTW it's even a bit simpler in the next version of `ggplot2`, as there will be no need to compute the summary manually because you can automatically limit the plot range to the summary instead of the raw data)